# Are upgrades per character?

Tags: adventure-time-etdbidk

If, for example, I pay enough treasure to upgrade Marcelline's health, would I have to pay again if I want to upgrade Jake's health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, upgrades are not shared at all, so you *will* have to pay for stat upgrades for each character individually. This means that if you get Upgrade 1 for Marceline's Thumps/Health for X amount of Treasures, you're going to have to get another X amount of Treasures in order to get Upgrade 1 for Jake's.

Comment: Aww, that really sucks.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yeah. :( It's one of the design decisions that's been received rather poorly.

Comment: Between that and losing all my treasure every time I am becoming very frustrated.

Comment: The loss of treasure between runs is a major complaint and bad design.  Max of 999 treasure is also a problem.  Only way NOT to lose your treasure to the 'Candy Tax' is to use the 'Mind Games' token when going into the dungeon.  This allows you to take your current treasure amount into the dungeon without losing it, but WILL take up a token slot.